# Selenium consent to cookie pop up

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, cookies, popup

I've been struggling with this for some time now I want to consent to the pop-up but selenium just doesn't want to click the consent button

I have tried:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/button[1]/p'))).click()
```

and

```
    wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"/html/body/div[2]")))
cookie = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/button[1]")))
cookie.click()
```

This is the website - https://scriptblox.com/ the pop up should appear right away

[image: what I see]

[image: Iframe]

Comment: Somehow I don't encounter the consent to the pop-up

Comment: @undetectedSelenium did you go to the URL with Python selenium?

Comment: Initially I visited manually and not even through Selenium-Python. You might be seeing this as a result of GDPR within EU.

Comment: No consent pop-up here as well - several IPs and locations checked. Visited with Selenium. However, I got that annoying puzzle captcha.

Comment: @undetectedSelenium Maybe try visiting the website from incognito mode?

Comment: @CoffexCS Can you explain how _visiting the website from incognito mode_ can make any significant difference?

Comment: @undetectedSelenium sorry, IDK, thought it would make a difference. 
But this is what I see - [link](https://www.linkpicture.com/q/image_2022-07-23_232732576.png)

Comment: @CoffexCS Unfortunately the link https://www.linkpicture.com/view.php?img=LPic62dc58ca43315776499276 opens a blank page. Instead update the question with the relevant text based HTML.

Comment: @undetectedSelenium wasn't sure how to add the HTML properly but I put in the image of the pop up and button

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Another try (but again, I cannot test it):

```
WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, "fc-cta-consent"))).click()
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working for me

Comment: Try now - made an edit.

Comment: still nothing. This is some kind of special pop up maybe?

Comment: see if undetected Selenium's response helps, if not I'll try a couple more tricks.

Comment: Ok, another try ... see if something happens. What area are you though, what country, so I can set my IP there, so I can see the popup?

Comment: It's Latvia / Riga and the undetected selenium didn't work as well

Comment: Did `By.CLASS_NAME, "fc-cta-consent"` work?

Comment: No, didn't work as well

Answer (score 0):

To click on the element <kbd>Consent</kbd> you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.fc-consent-root button[aria-label='Consent'] p.fc-button-label"))).click()
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='fc-consent-root']//button[@aria-label='Consent']//p[@class='fc-button-label' and text()='Consent']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: Sadly nothing happens

Comment: Can share your thoughts why you need `frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it()`? Can you include the parent `<iframe>` tag as well in the snapshot? Presumably, you haven't switched the `iframe` properly.

Comment: I edited the post and added a snapshot of the iframes above. I'm not sure what I'm looking at tho

Comment: Seems like that problem is only for me. My friend tried out the code and it worked for him but not for me

Comment: Reboot/restart your test system, and start afresh, that may work out. All I can say the _`locators`_ suggested here are flawless :)